# how to get and decode data from XML in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, base64

im looking for a way to get specified data from element of XML file and if there are more elements with same name save them into separate Files.

im working with XML files that have structure like:

```
<Envelope>
  <message>
     <Object  Name="attachment1.xml">Data encoded in Base64</object>
     <Object  Name="attachment3.xml">Data encoded in Base64</object>
     <Object  Name="attachment3.xml">Data encoded in Base64</object>
  </message>
</Envelope>
```

It would save me a lot of time if i would be able to grab each Data of Objects, decode them and save as their attachment names.

Ive been trough a lots of google results, but im not able to write/compile the right code.

Thanks in advance.
J.

Comment: You have been through a lot of Google results, but you have not managed to find one that shows you how to select nodes from XML in PowerShell, and not one that shows you how to decode Base64 in PowerShell? Those pretty basic operations, there is no way that you have searched and found nothing.

Comment: First, fix *Error: "The 'Object' start tag on line
3 position 7 does not match the end tag of 'object'. Line 3, position 62."*

Comment: That's why I literally gave you the things to search for in my comment. "how to select nodes from XML in PowerShell" and "to decode Base64 in PowerShell". I'm sure there is going to be *plenty* of example material to work through.

Comment: @Tomalak Hi, im usually able to find a solution of what i need to do(compile found scripts for my purpose) but it looks like in this case im not able to properly articulate the operation im looking for because of lack of my overview for this terminology. 

EDIT: thanks im going to dig deeper into your suggestions.